# Background image location - wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Can someone give me a suggestion of where a background image may be found in Wordpress? It's a custom made theme and the developer is no longer an option to contact.

I've attached a screenshot. I'm trying to change out the green round image (see red arrow in screenshot below), but because it's part of the background and not an image I cannot find it within Wordpress to edit it.

The website is www.drlindatucker.com

I would appreciate any suggestions - I'm pulling my hair out over this.

Thank you!

http://screencast.com/t/b7YVJ9lnJXT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think, you can change it in wordpress backend.
The file you're looking for is: `/dev/wp-content/themes/Nature-LT/images/icon-podcast-title.png`. You can change it or have a look in your CSS file, but it's minified, so I can't tell you the line.